# Long term engine issues by using Active Exhaust?

Tags: engine, exhaust

Looking to install OEM active valve mufflers on my 2019 Mustang EcoBoost.

Wondering if the valves opening and closing, thus changing exhaust back-pressure would cause the engine to run lean/rich and do long term harm to my bone stock car.

Long term reliability has priority over sound for me but if it has ZERO effect then I will go ahead and do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would the manufacturer have done any testing for this before making it available?

Comment: Yes but my car’s computer wouldn’t know about the new  mufflers since I’m doing it myself.

Comment: Cross posted and answered here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/37357/10902